# Highlight elements on table in revealJS Quarto

Tags: r, highlight, quarto, reveal.js

I have a table in a revealjs Quarto slide. I would like to `.fade-in` and highlight a value of the table. For example, I would like to highlight the value 3.2 of Sepal.Width in the example below:

````
---
title: "Highlight elements on table"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

I would like to fade-in a highlight (color) a piece of text.

```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(head(iris))
```
````

Output:

[image]

Ideally it would look like something like this (created in paint):

[image]

As @Julian already suggested, we may use the [roughnotation](https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/quarto-roughnotation) extension, but this can only highlight words in your slide and not anything you want on a slide. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to highlight a value like in the example above in revealjs Quarto?

Comment: Why not using [chalkboard](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/presenting.html#chalkboard) ??

Comment: Hi @shafee, Because then I have to draw every time when I need to highlight something. I would like to automatically highlight a value like `fade-in` a color. It doesn't need to be a circle like in the example above. That was just an example. Do you understand what I mean? Thanks

Comment: Yes. But you can save your highlighted drawings (sort of pre-recording) and then get those highlights every time you render the document thereafter. Does this work for you?

Comment: @shafee, Could you please share a reproducible example? I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [restore](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/presenting.html#restoring-drawings) the highlighted drawings after you have highlighted things on the revealjs slides.

- Suppose, at first render the following document,

  ```
  ---
  title: "Using Chalkboard"
  format: 
    revealjs:
      chalkboard: true
  ---

  ## Quarto

  Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation.
  ```
- And then highlight lines as you want.
- Once you are done highlighting, press `D` key to download the drawings in a JSON file.
- Now you can refer to this JSON file via the `src` option under `chalkboard` key to get those previously done highlights every time you render the document.

  ```
  ---
  title: "Using Chalkboard"
  format: 
    revealjs:
      chalkboard: 
        src: chalkboard.json
  ---

  ## Quarto

  Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation.
  ```

Comment: Thank you @shafee for your answer! I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76021855/align-r-stack-layout-tables-in-revealjs-quarto) which may be a solution for this problem but only has one issue. Could you may have a look? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Oh, yes I have seen that. But I there is already an answer (and hopefully a correct one) :D