# Align r-stack layout tables in revealjs Quarto

Tags: r, kable, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to `fragment` two Kable tables in a [`.r-stack`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html) layout. The problem is that when the second table got a colored value, the table doesn't align well anymore after overlaying so it shows the column twice. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Align r-stack tables in revealjs"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

::: {.r-stack}

::: {.fragment}
```{r}
kbl(head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling(font_size = 15)
```

:::

::: {.fragment}
```{r}
iris = head(iris)
iris$Sepal.Width = cell_spec(head(iris$Sepal.Width), background = ifelse(head(iris$Sepal.Width) == 3.2, "red", "white"), align = 'initial')
head(iris) |>
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling(font_size = 15) 
```

:::

:::
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see the second table with the colored value of the Sepal.Width doesn't get stacked on the first table. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to align well two tables with r-stack layout in revealjs Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after applying the `cell_spec` the column is no longer a numeric column and hence gets aligned to the left by default. Hence, first step would be to align the column to the right. However, even after doing so there is a small discrepancy as adding the background adds some padding and moreover, zeros after the decimal point get dropped. Not an expert in `kableExtra` but one fix for these issues would be to use a `cell_spec` in the first table too (but note that there is still some padding on the right for the second column):

````
---
title: "Align r-stack tables in revealjs"
format: revealjs
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Slide

::: {.r-stack}

::: {.fragment}
```{r}
iris2 <- head(iris)
iris2$Sepal.Width <- cell_spec(iris2$Sepal.Width, background = "white")
iris2 |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, align = "rrrrl") |>
  kable_styling(font_size = 15)
```

:::

::: {.fragment}
```{r}
iris2 <- head(iris)
iris2$Sepal.Width <- cell_spec(iris2$Sepal.Width, background = ifelse(iris2$Sepal.Width == 3.2, "red", "white"))
iris2 |>
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, align = "rrrrl") |>
  kable_styling(font_size = 15)
```

:::

:::
````

[image]